# Windows error when trying to run a .robot file through PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pycharm, robotframework

I'm getting an error as below when trying to run my test case with .robot extension. I've Python 3.9.2 installed.

> "This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action. Please install an app or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Apps Settings page."

I've tried `regedit HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Lnkfile` and checked for `IsShortcut` string file but no luck.

What could be wrong or missing?

[image: Error message]

Comment: Have you selected proper interpreter in the pycharm? have installed robot framework in pycharm?